# Instantiate and scale unity UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in unity2d. I have gameobject with co-ordinate and it position and scale perfectly. I want to use that same co-ordinate to UI object instantiate position and scale like normal gameobject in c# script.

```
 void long_tile_func(Vector2 position_,List<int> counter)
{
    cam = Camera.main;
    Vector2 instantiate_pos = cam.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector2(position_.x,position_.y));
    instantiate_pos.y=instantiate_pos.y/10f;    
    instantiate_pos.x=instantiate_pos.x/10f;
    GameObject slider_=Instantiate(long_tile,position_,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    Vector3 v=new Vector3(5.3f,(Vector3.Distance(obj_1.transform.position,obj_3.transform.position)/4f));
    slider_.transform.localScale=v;
    slider_.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("background").transform,false);
}
```

I tried to convert co-ordinate to screenpoint with this function cam.ViewportToScreenPoint(). But it isn't work as much i expect..

Comment: When working with UI you shouldn't be setting the `localScale` at all but rather go through the [`RectTransform.sizeDelta`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html) which takes all the pivot and anchor settings into account

Comment: I tried this code : "UI.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta=v;" v is co-ordinate. I directly use co-ordinate and i convert coordinate to ViewportToScreenPoint before i assign to sizeDelta. But both make UI too small.

Comment: The sizes of the UI are usually in pixel space depending on your setup ..

Comment: yes UI size adjust based pixel. But i want more accurate. Eg : i have border line. I don't want UI object out of the border.